# how to change <table> columns inside any odoo page

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I'm new on python and odoo so excuse me for any dumb question

when I see a table inside any page, and I want to change the columns of it, maybe remove the (name) column and add (passport No) column ..etc
how can I do that?

this is the table that I mean

[image: tableImg]

I've clicked on the "bug" icon (developer Tools) and chooses (Edit View: Form) option

this is what I got

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

so now I'm sure that 
`<field name="slip_ids"/>`
is being converted to print the table.

so I've searched on this field name in the python file and I saw it's One2Many field

`slip_ids = fields.One2many('hr.payslip', 'payslip_run_id', string='Payslips', readonly=True, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]})`

also I've searched for "payslip_run_id" and this is what I got

`payslip_run_id = fields.Many2one('hr.payslip.run', string='Payslip Batches', readonly=True, copy=False, states={'draft': [('readonly', False)]})`

please help me, where I can find the code that tells (slip_ids) field to print the table with those specific columns ?
because I need to add other columns and remove some of the current

if there is anything that needs to be shared as well please let me know

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If inside One2many field, there is not any tree view defined that default it will take tree view which is available for that model.

So in your case it will take tree which is available for hr.payslip.
it can be `hr_payroll.view_hr_payslip_tree` this, if there is not any other tree view created.

Comment: thanks a lot, actually you opened my eyes on something calls (tree), I wasn't familiar with this concept, as I said I'm new at odoo and python. anyway now I've found the tree that has all the <field> tags, and it's inheriting from other tree as well, so you technically answered my question, thanks :)